# clear listbox when adding new record to form

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba

I'm using Access 2007. I have a form (details of a child) which contains a listbox that lists the child's special needs. The listbox is in a many-to-many relationship with the table of children and the table with the controlled list of special needs. The RowSource of the listbox is

```sql
SELECT Child.ID, Need.Category 
FROM Need INNER JOIN 
    (Child INNER JOIN [Child-Need] ON Child.ID = [Child-Need].[Child FK]) 
    ON Need.ID = [Child-Need].[Need FK] 
ORDER BY [Category];
```

When I try to add a new record, the listbox contents don't clear, continuing to be locked to the values relevant to the existing record.

How do I clear the listbox's contents so the user can add needs relevant to the new child?

*Subsequently, I have found that when moving from record to record on the form, the listbox contents remain those of the first record that appears. It looks as though I have a serious error, presumably in my SQL!*

Comment: `listboxName.requery` ??

Comment: Alas, no. Tried that!

Comment: Is this a bound form?

Comment: It is a subform of another form, Family. The other subform on the form, Carer, is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The rowsource has no reference to the current child that is displayed in the form.

I think you would need something like

```sql
SELECT Child.ID, Need.Category 
FROM Need INNER JOIN 
    (Child INNER JOIN [Child-Need] ON Child.ID=[Child-Need].[Need FK]) 
    ON Need.ID=[Child-Need].[Need ID] 
WHERE Child.ID = Forms!frmChild!ID
ORDER BY [Category];
```

(replace `frmChild` by your form name).

And then you need a `myListbox.Requery` in the `OnCurrent` event of the form, so it shows the current data when moving to a different record.

Edit: if it's a subform, it's something like

```
WHERE Child.ID = Forms!frmFamily!frmChild.Form!ID
```

see [Refer to Form and Subform properties and controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)

Comment: That feels right, except that I can't find a formulation for the second part of the WHERE clause that Access will accept. It asks me for the ID as a parameter when the form opens and on every change of child record. When I supply it, the right data appears. You're very close: mine would be 'Child.ID = Forms!frmFamilies!frmChild.Form!ID'.

Comment: If I added the listbox RowSource as part of the code in the OnCurrent event of the Child form, Access doesn't ask for parameters on opening the form. And it now works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code in the form load:

```
 Dim intItemsInList As Integer
 Dim intCounter As Integer

 intItemsInList = Me![lstTest].ListCount

 For intCounter = 0 To intItemsInList - 1
   Me![lstTest].RemoveItem 0
 Next
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I get an error on RemoveItem because the records are locked.